# How to change id to class toast notification and close button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, notifications

I have a simple toast notification code that I've collected from W3 Schools. But there's a problem. It use id, and we know that an id can be use for once. I want to change id and use it as class. So that I can use for many time. If it can be done by jquery, that will be also easy.

Another fact is that, I want to add a close button. So that, anyone can close it. As it disappear after 3 seconds, so there will be two option. Auto remove / fade out and closable system.

Look at my code:

`

```
<style type="text/css">
#snackbar {
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%; 
  bottom: 30px; 
}
#snackbar.show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
</style>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar</button>
<div id="snackbar">Some text some message..</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
  x.className = "show";
  setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}
</script>
```

`

How can I do it ?

Change id to class and add a close button to toast notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In css `#` is used as a prefix to select ids and `.` prefix is used to select based on class.

- Modify your HTML and use `class` name for toast divs
- Modify your CSS to specify rules for the `class` you used
- Modify the JavaScript code to use `document.getElementsByClassName` instead of `document.getElementById(..)`
- Further modify the JavaScript code to handle the returned element(s) in a loop as this method returns a `HTMLCollection` ([Click Here for API Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)).

Here is a quick jsFiddle I created with two toasts - https://jsfiddle.net/6hq2vzwu/

EDIT: Another (updated) version of the fiddle - you can click on the fist toast to close - https://jsfiddle.net/r9npkgc8/3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
        function myFunction() {
          var x = document.querySelector(".snackbar");
          x.className = "snackbar show";
          setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
        }
```

```css
.snackbar {
          visibility: hidden;
          min-width: 250px;
          margin-left: -125px;
          background-color: #333;
          color: #fff;
          text-align: center;
          border-radius: 2px;
          padding: 16px;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: 1;
          left: 50%; 
          bottom: 30px; 
        }
        .snackbar.show {
          visibility: visible;
          -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
          animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
          from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
          to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
        }
        @keyframes fadein {
          from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
          to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
          from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
          to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
        }
        @keyframes fadeout {
          from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
          to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
        }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar</button>
 <div class="snackbar">Some text some message..</div>
```